Choosing Between Organization and Personal Account for Google Play Console Integration
I'm working on integrating my app with the Google Play Console and I'm unsure whether to use a personal or organization account. I'm particularly interested in:

Easiest Integration: Which account type requires less setup and verification?
Challenges Faced: What are some common hurdles encountered with each account type?
Suggestions: Any recommendations for choosing between them based on development needs?

I've read about the limitations of personal accounts regarding features and scalability. However, I'm still unclear about the specific challenges of setting up and using an organization account, especially for smaller teams.
I integrated a personal account with the Google Play Console for my initial app release. I expected a quick and straightforward setup process, allowing me to publish the app easily.
